# How can I change the style of shiny fileInput object?

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking for how I can change the style of a fileInput button in shiny app to btn, btn-primary or any other possible style.

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(""),
  sidebarPanel(
  fileInput("file", "Select a file")  
  ),
mainPanel()
))
```

thanks

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Select a file")  
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  runjs("$('#file').parent().removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-danger');")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Stéphane and thank you for your answer. I have a doubt, how can I use your code to change also other characteristics of the FileInput button, as "background-color", "outline", "box-shadow", etc.? It seems that for this button the normal "style" isn't available. Thanks!