# upload button in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've some Shiny app with download button:

```
  column(width=1,downloadButton("downloadData", "download", class = "btn-success",style = "font-family:calibri;font-size: 45px !important;")),
```

I want also some button but just to upload file, I don't want to use "fileInput" because I want
to set style to my button and I don't want also the text box that comes with "fileInput",
I just want a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default `fileInput` and style-away the text input element used to show the filename.

```r
# modified https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447823/3358272
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Select a file")  
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  runjs("$('#file').parent().parent().siblings().removeClass('form-control').attr('hidden','true');")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: shiny fine input without filename input block]

Notes:

- You may want to finesse the rest of the styling of it, as two corners are rounded, two not.
- Depending on the interface, you are likely to see the input box momentarily before it is deleted. This is due to running this in javascript once the layout has already been set.
- I believe the encasing div is sized based on the input form element being present *before* it disappears.

There might be other interactions I haven't tested.

A better solution might be to implement this in raw CSS and read in from the start without running it in javascript. (I encourage somebody else to go that route.)

Comment: TY, but I want to styling the button exactly like the other button

Comment: CSS can do that for you, and there is not afaik a drop-in replacement. Good luck.